# ionic 3 drawer semi-transparent

Tags: ionic3

Is there any way I can make the navigation drawer semi-transparent, as displayed below?

[image]

I've tried setting the opacity of ion-content to 0.5

```
<ion-content class="menuDark">
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>


.menuDark{
        background: rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.5);
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

```
.menu-inner{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

in your app.scss

Comment: Wow never thought it was this straight forward. Thanks!